# Habits tags - do we need them all?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) and [breaking-bad-writing-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad-writing-habits). And also the related [psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing).

Shouldn't [breaking-bad-writing-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad-writing-habits) be merged into [habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits)?

What about [habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) - is it perhaps included in [psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing)?

(I'm sure of the first one, less so on the second.)

Comment: +1 always in favor of reducing the number of tags. Less is more :)

Answer (score 12):

[habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) and [breaking-bad-writing-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad-writing-habits) should be merged.  The latter is a subset of the former.  Neither has many questions (17 and 10) and they just aren't distinct enough to warrant the need for both.

[psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing) seems different (out of 48 questions, only 3 are tagged with either habit tag).  I'm okay with leaving it as is.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that something along the lines of [work-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-habits) or [work-discipline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-discipline) would cover the [discipline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline), [habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits), and [breaking-bad-writing-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad-writing-habits) cases and express the intent more clearly. I agree that [psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing) is a different subject.

Comment: habits could also refer to habitual word use, though, which is not covered by either tag proposal.

Comment: Oh geez I didn't even realize there was a [tag:discipline] tag too.  Yeah, that should be a synonym of habits.

Comment: I agree with you about the merging but didn't upvote because I'd rather see the more generic [tag:habits] stay as the main tag.  I'd put [tag:discipline] as a synonym and merge the rest.

Comment: @Cyn There is such a thing as being too generic, though. if there are, as WeckarE. suggests, other types of habits, then we should distinguish them. And the other problem with generic tags is that people can be unsure what they apply to and may not use them as they should. I think [tag:work-habits] is unambiguous and specific, and if there are other habits we should care about, they should be similarly disambiguated ([tag:linguistic-habits], perhaps.

Comment: I agree with not getting too generic, but I don't think habits is that.  It's not a widely used tag so I don't see a need to divide out types of habits (there's enough continuity to justify keeping them together; it's not an artificial category).

Comment: Agreed. If questions relating to other habits pop up we can give those tags as they come up.

Comment: I can see the "habits" ones staying distinct or merging (but merging is fine), but I feel Psychology of Writing is very distinct.  *Habits* can cover, for example, both things you habitually do *in the text* ("How do I vary my sentence starts in a first person novel?") , or *writer-habits* ("I used to start writing sprints with a cup of coffee, but now I have to limit caffeine...what else can work?").  **Psych of writing** is about the **writer**, imho.  "I'm afraid to start/fail/succeed." "My character needs XYZ, but that's too close to my own trauma."

Comment: Perhaps a useful separation may be Writer vs Text? The ambiguity is the word "writing" can refer to the text itself or the action of the writer.  So perhaps "Writer Psychology" may be a more clarifying rename, and the Habits ones should be divided into those of the writer, and those within the text? (I'm blanking on good distinguishing names, and the writer-one would ultimately be folded into Writer's Psych, imho?)

Answer (score -2):

## All three tags are distinct and should remain

I'll start by quoting the tag info for each tag.

- [habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits): *"Writing habits, routines, and systems for writing."*
- [breaking-bad-writing-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad-writing-habits): *"This tag should be used for questions that are searching for common techniques to combat bad writing habits that might hinder your progress."*
- [psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing): *"This tag should be used for questions that deal with the psychological aspects of the task of writing something, such as when asking about the feelings you have before, during and after your writing or about the psychological background of getting yourself to work by for example setting goals and treating yourself to for example cookies after you have finished your current writing goal."*

To me, each of these serves a unique role, though there is certainly overlap I believe they are distinct enough from each other to remain.

[habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) is about the things that we do, though I am only so-so about its existance and would never use it myself I don't think it is a bad tag and it does aptly describe most of the questions where is it used.

[breaking-bad-writing-habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad-writing-habits) is about the techniques to fix our bad habits, not about the habits themselves. Though very related I don't believe they are the same topic. In fact I feel this tag has as much or more to do with [discipline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline) as it does with [habits](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits).

[psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing) is a different tag entirely. Where the other two tags are about *what* we do this tag focuses on the *why* and the *how* of the writing craft. I feel it does have some crossover with the [writer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writer) tag but not with the habit tags above.

Comment: Is your suggestion to make breaking bad habits a synonym of discipline?

Comment: @NofP I'm not suggesting it. But I am saying that you could make an equally good case to merge it as you can to merge with habits therefore it should be merged with neither.